# How to define INNER JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have a problem how to define INNER JOIN in SQL. The problem is that I have a table `Names` with columns `ID` and `Name`. The other table has column `PersonID`.

Sometimes value in column `PersonID` is 0, and in `Names` table there is no row with a column value of 0.

I have created a view, and I am using an `INNER JOIN`. Problem is that `SELECT` statement in the view only works when there is value greater than zero in column `PersonID`.

How can I define an `INNER JOIN` when value is 0, so that column is NULL, and when is not zero then value should be `Name` from `Names`?

What I mean is:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.Test
AS
    SELECT 
        a.Column1,
        a.Column2,
        ...,
        CASE
            WHEN a.PersonID IS NULL 
                THEN '' 
                ELSE b.Name
        END AS PersonName
    FROM 
        dbo.ExampleA AS a
    INNER JOIN 
        -- What to put in here that value is NULL when PersonID = 0,
        -- and when PersonID > 0 then join value should be a.PersonID = b.ID?            
        dbo.Names AS b ON ???
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an outer join instead of an inner join.  An alternative would be to UNION ALL  just the 0 row back in, setting all the column values from the 2nd table to NULL

Comment: You are after a left join, why you should use an INNER join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.Colum1, e.Colum2, . . . ,
       COALESCE(e.name, n.Name) AS PersonName
FROM dbo.ExampleA e LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Names n
     ON n.personid = e.personid;
```

Note that this also changes the table aliases to *meaningful* abbreviations for the tables.  And uses `COALESCE()` instead of `CASE`.

Comment: Yes, LEFT JOIN is what I need. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use LEFT JOIN instead. ie:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.Test
AS
SELECT a.Colum1,
    a.Colum2,
    ...,
    Coalesce(b.Name,'') AS PersonName
FROM dbo.ExampleA AS a
LEFT JOIN dbo.Names AS b
    ON a.PersonId = b.Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using a union all..

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.Test
AS
    SELECT 
        a.Column1,
        a.Column2,
        ...,
        b.Name as PersonName
    FROM dbo.SomeTableName AS a
    INNER JOIN Names on A.PERSONID = B.ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        a.Column1,
        a.Column2,
        ...,
        '' as PersonName
    FROM dbo.SomeTableName as A
    WHERE A.PersonID = 0
```